# Put two texts in one div (logo and nav)

Tags: css, html

I want to make one navbar on the top of the page hold both a logo and some menu items, like seen on www.adidas.se. However I dont want to use an image as logo, just plain text will do. So basically on the right of the navbar there will be a logotext and from the left side there will be an unordered list that will hold the menu items. I need the logo text to be larger than the other text.

This is my code so far:

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
background: yellow;
font-family: 'Josefin', sans-serif;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
}

.header {
background: red;
color: white;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html lang="sv-se">
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>TITLE TEXT</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="header">
<h1>LOGO</h1>
</div>

<div class="nav">


<ul>
<li><a href="">ITEM 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">ITEM 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">ITEM 3</a></li>
<li><a href="">ITEM 4</a></li>
</ul>


</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your elements are all rendering in block.  Try changing them to display:inline-block.

Comment: At _adidas.se_ the logo is left, with menu immediate followed ... you wrote _on the right be logo and from left side menu_, so which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest is using `display:inline-block` for most of your positioning. Check the snippet below and let me know if it helps, and if you need more help or clarification :)

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
background: yellow;
font-family: 'Josefin', sans-serif;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
}

.header {
background: red;
color: white;
position: relative;
}

.nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }

.nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  }
.header h1{
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="sv-se">
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>TITLE TEXT</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="header">
<h1>LOGO</h1>
  <div class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="">ITEM 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">ITEM 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">ITEM 3</a></li>
<li><a href="">ITEM 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is all that's really needed.  The other suggestions to use floats and flex are more likely to break the CSS than achieve the desired results.

Comment: Glad it helped! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Make the header a fixed-width container with `position: relative`, and the list and `h1` absolutely positioned inline-blocks inside the header, with `bottom` and `left/right` values as below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: yellow;
  font-family: 'Josefin', sans-serif;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
.header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="sv-se">

<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>TITLE TEXT</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="header">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">ITEM 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">ITEM 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">ITEM 3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">ITEM 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h1>LOGO</h1>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the ideal would be to put all your header info in a div or a `header` and then float the information inside.

```css
header {
 background: red;
 color: white;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
}
.header, .nav {
 float: left;
}

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
background: yellow;
font-family: 'Josefin', sans-serif;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
}

.header {
background: red;
color: white;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="container">
  <header>
   <div class="header">
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
   </div>

   <div class="nav">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="">ITEM 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">ITEM 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">ITEM 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="">ITEM 4</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </header>
 </div>
</body>
```

But after that, you would still have to style a lot of things, like your `nav`. There is still a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
background: yellow;
font-family: 'Josefin', sans-serif;
}

.header-container {
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    background:#acacac;
}

.header-text {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    font-size:2em;
}

.nav {
    display:inline-block;

}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="sv-se">
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>TITLE TEXT</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header-container">

    <div class="header-text">
        LOGO
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">ITEM 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ITEM 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ITEM 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ITEM 4</a></li>
    </ul>


    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```